# Combine Confidence Intervals and Odds Ratios + Adding Starts for P-Values in Gtsummary

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, gtsummary

Two simple questions here. First, is there a way to combine the confidence intervals and the odds ratios into a single column with gtsummary for the tblregression/tbl_uvyregression functions? Second, is it possible to include stars to indicate the significance level for the p-values (i.e. *<.05, **<.01, ***<.005) so I do not have to have a p-value column whenever I make a table? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of gtsummary v1.4.0, this is possible with the `add_significance_stars()` function.

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #Uighur
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.0'

tbl <-
  lm(marker ~ age + grade, trial) %>%
  tbl_regression() %>%
  add_significance_stars(
    pattern = "{estimate} ({conf.low}, {conf.high}){stars}",
    hide_se = TRUE
  ) %>%
  modify_header(estimate ~ "**Beta (95% CI)**")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Wow, an unbelievably comprehensive and helpful answer. Thank you so much! I am in clinical psychology/epidemiology, and here are some journals I've come across that I've seen formatted with coefficients and CI's in a single column and/or having significance stars:    -Clinical Psych Science
    -Journal of Psychopharmacology
    -Addiction
    -Drug and Alcohol Dependence. Thanks again for being so responsive and so incredibly thoughtful!

Comment: Great, if you can post an issue to the gtsummary GitHub page with this information, and please link to published guidelines where applicable. That will get these journals on the list to support!

Comment: Done! Thank you so much, really looking forward to the next version of gtsummary! Thank you for this amazing work.